# Generate Test Load for server from client

Tags: netty

Question 1:

I am using timers in my workload generator client to stream messages to the server. Are there any implications of using multiple timertasks on the number of threads created or the sharing of the Channel ?

I want to understand if this is a preferred approach to generate load. I might have other exponential delays or other types of delays in this way.

```
public class TestClientHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

private Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();

Channel channel;

public TestClientHandler() {
    timer.newTimeout( new DataStreamer( this ),
                      1000, 
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();

        org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
}

  @Override
  public void channelConnected( ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                                ChannelStateEvent e) {


      this.channel = e.getChannel();

      ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write( "SOMETHING" );

  }
```

}

Question 2:

How do I maintain different channels for different types of requests ? Are there priority based ideas ? Is OrderAwareMemoryHandler the recommended way to plugin in a PriorityBlockingQueue like it is discussed in another thread ?

Answer (score 1):

q1: I am not sure if I correctly understood the Q1. Just, I can say that HashedWeelTimer is a single threaded timer task manager -> All tasks you pass in are executed by one thread.

q2: is unclear to me

Comment: Q1: So it is only one thread. Is there a way in Netty to get the workload generated in multiple threads ? I can run multiple clients but I was trying to using any feature Netty has to run multiple threads in the client. I know concurrency frameworks do this. Q2. Can I use SLA's on the server by allocating separate channels ? Hope this makes sense because NIO itself is based on events. Messages on one Channel will be processed by Netty while messages of a different type are accorded lower priority. Is this even sensible ?

Comment: Q1: Normally when you create a new channel, netty assigns it to a worker thread. The total number of worker threads is Number_of_cores*2 by default. When you create more channels than worker threads, more channels are assigned to one worker thread. So to create multithreaded load you should create more channels. To have more threads adjust "workerCount" parameter for NioClientSocketChannelFactory.